# Laptop becomes slow

Tags: ram, swap

I had attached my laptop specifications. I use chromium browser, microsoft teams for work. In an 8 hrs of work, my laptop slowly becomes slower by around 3 - 4hrs of work.

When I restart my laptop, it gets speed. How to resolve this without restarting everytime? Do I need to clean ram memory frequently?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: If it's a RAM problem caused by web browsers, just close some tabs and you will see how it gets fast. If you close the browsers or even clean the swap memory and the computer it's still slow, then it would not be a RAM problem.

Comment: 4GB RAM is barely enough these days ... [zram](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/blockdev/zram.html) might actually help in your case ... to enable zram support run `sudo apt install zram-config` then reboot.

Comment: @heynnema OP updated the question, but mistakenly tagged you in a comment in the answer below, and you probably did not get a notification.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too little RAM, and too little SWAP. Ultimately you should add more RAM.

Let's try and compensate by increasing your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: I feel difficult to execute above command. Let's do it using remote computer logging in. We shall arrange a time to do. My email id is sivasdpi@gmail.com. pls send ur email address

Comment: @sivasdpi As long as you copy/paste the commands into `terminal`, you should be able to do this yourself. Everything after the # is a comment, so you don't need to copy that part of the line, only the command part. The whole process takes less than 5 minutes.

Comment: @sivasdpi Status please...

Comment: Will update soon @heynnema

Comment: I had uploaded the result above. Pls check if I did correct.

Comment: @sivasdpi It all looks good except for the last step, where you verify the /swapfile line in /etc/fstab. It's probably ok, but go ahead and review it. If the slowness situation is improved, please remember to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I will work for 4 days and see how it performs. Then sure will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: After a week of usage I found laptop didn't freezed too much. It improved. It freezes 2 times only browser freezed. I just restarted browser rather than restarting laptop. It is okay for me. Thanks. I gave a check mark to your answer. Pls share your personal email address to ask doubts.

Comment: @sivasdpi Good news! Thanks for the update. Consider adding more RAM.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely happening because the physical RAM is getting filled up, and the computer is using a part of the Hard Disk as memory. This is known as [swap](https://averagelinuxuser.com/linux-swap/).

Increasing the swap or changing the amount of swappiness may not help much, as swap is inherently slow, and it is quite clear that you are not running out of swap (then the computer would freeze).

You can try the following.

1. When the computer becomes slow, close Chromium and Teams, and open a Terminal. Temporarily move the memory from swap to RAM with the command

   ```
   sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a
   ```

And the computer should become more responsive again.

2. Using alternatives - as per my experience, Firefox consumes less RAM per tab than Chromium. Also, the web interface of Teams at https://teams.microsoft.com consumes less memory than the Teams client (irrespective of whether you use Firefox or Chromium).
3. Switch to a lighter distro like Lubuntu. However, this may not change the scenario too much in case you are using several Chromium tabs and Microsoft Teams simultaneously.
4. Consider upgrading the amount of RAM.

Comment: Can I execute above command without closing chromium, teams ? Because it requires continuous work flow

Comment: @sivasdpi You can try, but in case Chromium + Teams consume more memory than your RAM, it might freeze your computer. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Web interface of teams also don't navigate within them quickly. It responds slowly. Will install Lubuntu and see how it works.

Comment: @sivasdpi You can try the command `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a` once. If it works and does not freeze your computer, you may not have to switch operating systems.

Comment: Thanks @Archisman. Will check and inform you.

Comment: @heynnema I had executed your commands and posted above results . Pls check and do the needful

Comment: I executed ur command. It doesn't give any result . Felt little improvement in performance . Will check for another 2 - 3 days and inform