# How to Speed up my PC?

Tags: 20.04, visual-studio-code, web-development

## Hello Everyone

How can I speed up my Asus X555LA Laptop while developing apps from Next JS and VS code . So while developing such React and Next JS apps my laptop hangs a lot. My Laptop's configurations are:

> Ram : 4gb

> CPU : Intel® Core™ i3-4030U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

> Graphics : Intel® HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)

> Disk Space: 500gb

> OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

> OS Type: 64 bit

> Gnome Version : 3.36.8

> Windowing System : x11

I Tried Updating my Ram but I dont get 8gb ram due to the lockdown. so upgradation of my hardware will not be possible right now.

### Thankyou in Advance

Comment: This is very similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/1358364/124466 Try increasing swap as explained there. Also consider switching to Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Comment: You seem to be at the minimum configuration for Ubuntu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements Assuming that you do not want to switch to a lighter flavor of Ubuntu  and you have a hard disk, you can switch to an SSD and add swap.

Comment: Thats right but I cant switch other operating system and cant upgrade my laptop components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ) or install other desktop alongside, wide spectrum exists - from plaint Openbox to LXDE, MATE or Xfce.

Comment: I have 2gb Swap and How can I make it 4gb

Comment: @KevalShah Check out the link I shared above. There is a detailed answer explaining how to increase swap. Note that swap is inherently slow, increasing it may not change performance too much.

Comment: Replacing a hard disk with an SSD is a relatively easy process. After replacing your disk, it will be more meaningful to use swap.

Comment: Using an old HDD is the major bottleneck here indeed.