# Ubuntu runs very slow (version 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, performance

I bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't understand why it gets so slow. When I run the `htop` command I cant really understand why my computer runs slow.

`htop` picture:

[image: htop_pic]

System info:

[image: pc_info]

Comment: As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybelz.jpg), the memory is all used up, and the computer is using swap, which is much slower. You can restart the computer to temporarily fix this. To avoid this do not use too many memory hungry programs (chrome, VS Code) simultaneously, and also, consider switching to a lighter operating system like Xubuntu or Lubuntu. In future, please post the terminal output as text, instead of posting an image. See https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Also, it is Ubuntu, not "Ubunto"

Comment: but is chrome so slow that it takes all the memory?

Comment: It's not about being slow. Chrome is a memory hungry app, and VS Code is a fancy website running inside a chrome-like (electron) window. From my experience, Firefox is relatively better in memory consumption. As a workaround, close Chrome and VS Code, and try the command `sudo swapoff -a && sudo swapon -a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laptop becomes slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358364/laptop-becomes-slow)